# Compatibility Condition of the Poisson Equation with Neumann Boundary Conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, integral-transforms, boundary-value-problem

I am trying to solve the following general Poisson equation with homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions in a rectangular domain ($0 \le x \le L$ and $0 \le y \le H$).
$$  
  \frac{\partial^2 p(x,y)}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 p(x,y)}{\partial y^2} = \, b(x,y) \\
  \left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial y} \right)_{y=0}=0; \qquad
  \left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial y} \right)_{y=H}=0 \\
  \left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} \right)_{x=0}=0; \qquad
  \left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} \right)_{x=L}=0 \\
$$
where $b(x,y)$ is a known source term function.

This general Poisson equation doesn't comply with the compatibility condition for all possibilities of $b(x,y)$.
Then, the following change of variable is proposed:
$$
p(x,y)=p^*(x,y)+F(x,y)
$$
where $p^*(x,y)$ is a new variable and $F(x,y)$ is an arbitrary function that **must** satisfy:

$$
  \left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \right)_{x=L} = 0 \qquad (1)\\
  \left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \right)_{x=0} = 0 \qquad (2)
$$

Applying this change of variable in the original problem, one can get to the following formulation:

$$ 
\frac{\partial^2 p^*(x,y)}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 p^*}{\partial y^2} =
 \, b(x,y) - \frac{\partial^2 F(x,y)}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^2 F(x,y)}{\partial y^2} \\
  \left( \frac{\partial p^*}{\partial y} \right)_{y=0} = - \left(\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}\right)_{y=0}; \qquad
  \left( \frac{\partial p^*}{\partial y} \right)_{y=H} = - \left(\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}\right)_{y=H}\\
  \left( \frac{\partial p^*}{\partial x} \right)_{x=0} = 0; \qquad
  \left( \frac{\partial p^*}{\partial x} \right)_{x=L} = 0 \\
$$

For this new problem, the following compatibility condition must be satisfied for this formulation to be mathematically well-posed:

$$
 - \int_0^L \left(\left[\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \right)_{y=H}  - \left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \right)_{y=0}\right] \right) \, d x = \\
  \int_0^H \int_0^L  \, b(x,y) \, d x \, d y -
  \int_0^H \int_0^L \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} \, d x \, d y -
  \int_0^H \int_0^L \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2} \, d x \, d y
$$

After simplifications, one can arrive at the following equation:
$$
  \int_0^H \int_0^L \left(  \, b(x,y) -
  \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} \right)\, d x \, d y
  =
  0 \qquad (3)
$$

I am having trouble to find a function $F(x,y)$ that satisfies the compatibility equation (3) and the boundary conditions for the $x$ direction (1) and (2) described above. I need this function to guarantee that the problem is always well-posed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify (3) even further. Using the fundamental theorem of calculus and (1)--(2): 
$$\int_0^H \int_0^L \left(  \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} \right)\, d x \, d y   =
\int_0^H  \left(  \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \right)\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=L} \, d y = \int_0^H 0\,dy =0 $$ 
Thus, (3) says that 
$$\int_0^H \int_0^L      b(x,y) \, d x \, d y  =   0  $$
which is precisely the compatibility condition for the original equation. The introduction of $F$ did not win you anything.